# why dose this thread code output differently?

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition

I'm trying to wrap my head wrap my head around threads, I would like to have only one direction of car on the bridge at a time at at the moment only east bound cars work. i commented out line 37's randomized+ direction function and when substituting in "east"code works as expected, but when running "west" it hold and theres my issue. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAXCARS 5
#define MAXWAIT 10
#define CROSSINGTIME 2

int G_direction = 0;
int carNum;
int retVal=0, lower = 0, upper = 1;
int car_rid[MAXCARS];
pthread_t threads[MAXCARS];

sem_t direc_sem, car_E, car_W,bridge_sem;

const char* printRandoms() ///randomise the cars direction
{
    int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    if (num == 0){
        //left headed west
        return "west";
    }else return "east";
    //return num;
    
}
void *car(void *arg) {
    int carNum = (int)(intptr_t)arg; //what car is it 
    const char* direction = "west";//printRandoms(); //random direction
    printf("car no %d is idling, planning to go %s \n",carNum, direction);// test print
    sleep( rand() % MAXWAIT ); // wait a random amounnt of time 

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(strcmp(direction,"west") == 0){
        if (G_direction > 0){//g_direction 1 = one car headed east 2 two headed east
            sem_wait(&car_E);//if traffic flow is in the wrong direction wait for the semaphore
        }
        G_direction--;//->> move ON the bridge
        if (G_direction == -1){//if last car on bridge lock west bound traffic
            sem_wait(&car_W);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(strcmp(direction,"east") == 0){
        if (G_direction < 0){//g_direction 1 = one car headed east 2 two headed east
            sem_wait(&car_W);//if traffic flow is in the wrong direction wait for the semaphore
        }
        G_direction++;//->> move ON the bridge
        if (G_direction == 1){//if last car on bridge lock west bound traffic
            sem_wait(&car_E);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

   
    printf("car no %d goes ON the bridge heading %s \n", carNum,direction);
    
    sleep(CROSSINGTIME);
   
    printf("car no %d goes OFF the bridge heading %s \n", carNum, direction);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(strcmp(direction, "west") == 0){
        
        G_direction++;//->> move OFF the bridge
        if (G_direction == 0){//if last car on bridge unlock other traffic
            sem_post(&car_W);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(strcmp(direction,"east") == 0){
        
        G_direction--;//->> move off the bridge
        if (G_direction == 0){//if last car on bridge unlock other traffic
            sem_post(&car_E);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    

}

int main( void ){
    sem_init(&direc_sem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&car_E, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&bridge_sem, 0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCARS; i++){
       retVal = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,car ,(void *)(intptr_t)i);
        if(retVal!=0){
           printf("pthread_create failed in %d_th pass\n",i);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
       }
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < MAXCARS; i++){
        retVal = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if(retVal!=0){
               printf("pthread_join failed in %d_th pass\n",i);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
        }
    }
   
    //sem_destroy(&carLock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code review note. A car can be going in one of two directions, yes? Store this as a variable, `isHeadingEast` (or west, just pick one and be consistent). Do not do slow operations like string compares to try to figure out which way a car is going. When you need a string, have **one** piece of code that takes the variable and returns a `char*` that's "east" or "west". I think if you rewrite your code like this, your problem will become obvious

Comment: thank you i will do a bit of a rewrite and see if i can get to the bottom of it. if nothing else it will give me a fresh start

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `sem_init(&car_W, 0, 1);`?

Comment: i did miss that thank you , but im even more confused now as the output dosn't change ...

Comment: You might like to insert a printf before every `sem_wait`.  There are several places in the code that look like potential deadlocks and this might help you find the one in question.  Also look at tools like ThreadSanitizer which are meant to help detect race conditions.